# Performing an intermediate sorted group-by operation on a Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a Java `Stream` of tuple objects like so:

```
{ 1, 2 }
{ 1, 6 }
{ 2, 3 }
{ 3, 10 }
{ 3, 12 }
{ 3, 20 }
```

These tuples are guaranteed to be ordered by their first element. I want to convert this stream into another stream of tuples like so:

```
{ 1, [2, 6] }
{ 2, [3] }
{ 3, [10, 12, 20] }
```

But, here's the key, I want this to be an *intermediate* operation - I don't need to evaluate the entirety of the first stream to output each group, because the tuples are already ordered as required. What I want is something like an intermediate collector, but I can't find a way of doing that in the stream API.

Can anyone think of a way of doing this without iterating the entire stream?

Comment: I see that OP himself agreed that it's duplicate, but it's somewhat different question. The linked one provides a solution to create stream of lists like `[{1, 2}, {1, 6}], [{2, 3}], [{3, 10}, {3, 12}, {3, 20}]`. Of course it can be easily mapped to get the result the OP wants, but this introduces an overhead of creating the intermediate lists. It would be interesting to find more efficient solution...

Comment: I agree, but the issue is that there is no general 'tuple' type in Java, so any implementation like that would depend on your specific tuple representation. Certainly, for my case, the linked answer works, as I can just extract the overall key from the first item in each grouping.